# How to add more RSU node on Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm facing some problem when trying to add more RSU node on veins example code.
Here's the code I added in RSUExampleScenario.ned

```
rsu[2]: RSU {
        @display("p=162,140;i=veins/sign/yellowdiamond;is=vs");
    }
```

And more codes in .ini

```
*.rsu[1].mobility.x = 1800
*.rsu[1].mobility.y = 1800
*.rsu[1].mobility.z = 2
```

When I try to start the simulation,error message says

> Error: Name 'rsu' is not unique within its component

I'd really appreciate with some help to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is a bit confusing here. You should not add this code, but rather replace `rsu[1]` with `rsu[n]`, where n is the amount of nodes you want. You can then specify the location of each in the omnetpp.ini as you're doing here. Check out [this part of the OMNeT++ tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part4/) for more details. This has the following example:

```
    network Tictoc10
    {
    submodules:
        tic[6]: Txc10;
```

> Here we created 6 modules as a module vector...

Comment: I get it! I misunderstanding the name rsu[1] to be a specific object name so I create the second node with rsu[2],but it's actually an array structure so I should change the number in [] to add more rsu.Thanks alot for the help,really appreciate.

Comment: Sir,I'm wondering in this example code,how does the data transmission being manipulated,there's no .cc file to control it.I'm hoping to arrange the schedule of data transmission